# Using ReadBytes in Indy/Lazarus

Tags: sockets, indy, lazarus

I'm using Indy with Lazarus to write a socket application. Here is my code below.
The socket connects properly, but when sending packets to the server, it doesn't receive anything. I must be missing something. Thanks!

```
procedure TSocket.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Socket_Receive_Buffer: TIdBytes;
  Socket_Input_Length: integer;

begin
  with AContext.Connection do
  begin
    IOHandler.ReadBytes(Socket_Receive_Buffer, 1024, False);
    ShowMessage('Getting bytes');
    Socket_Input_Length := Length(Socket_Receive_Buffer);
    if Socket_Input_Length > 0 then
    begin
      Writeln('received something: nb bytes = '+IntToStr(Socket_Input_Length));
    end;
  end;
end;

function TSocket.Open: boolean;

begin
  if Settings.SocketModeRadioGroup.ItemIndex = 0 then
  begin
    IdTcpServer1 := TIdTCPServer.Create(nil);
    IdTCPServer1.OnExecute := @IdTCPServer1Execute;
    IdTCPServer1.OnConnect := @IdTCPServer1Connect;
    IdTCPServer1.OnDisconnect := @IdTCPServer1Disconnect;
    IdTcpServer1.DefaultPort := StrToInt(Settings.SocketPortEdit.Text);
    IdTcpServer1.MaxConnections := 1;
    IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
    IdTcpServer1.Active := True;
    Writeln('Server started. Listening for messages');
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Client');

    IdTcpClient1 := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
    //IdTcpClient1.DefaultPort := StrToInt(Settings.SocketPortEdit.SelText);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Where is the code that is sending data to the server?

Comment: `TIdTCPServer` is multithreaded, but `ShowMessage()` is not thread-safe.

Comment: The client is a separate known good software.

Answer (score 1):

The server is expecting to receive exactly 1024 bytes per message, no more no less.  Is the client actually sending 1024 bytes?  I am guessing no.  `ReadBytes(1024)` does not exit until 1024 bytes have been read in full, it does not read fewer bytes. If you need that kind of functionality, pass -1 instead of 1024. `ReadBytes(-1)` will return whatever bytes are currently available at that moment.

Comment: Changing 1024 for -1 solved partly the problem. Now, the server displays only null bytes (0x00) instead of the data. Note that I don't use any protocol in the data, so bytes can have any value from 0x00 to 0xFF.

Comment: `ReadBytes()` doesn't care what the actual bytes are. It receives what was actually sent. If you are getting null bytes, than either that is what came off the socket, or you are not processing the contents of the `TIdBytes` correctly after reading it. As for the data itself, you need a protocol, otherwise how do you expect to process the data correctly? You have to know where one message ends and the next begins, and how the message content is encoded. That is all dictated by the protocol.

Comment: Concerning the protocol, it's because I'm making a tool that allows to send data on a socket in a "protocol agnostic" fashion, for debugging or experimenting purpose. See 'Protocol Tool' at sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, finally.

```
procedure TSocket.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Socket_Receive_Buffer: TIdBytes;
  Socket_Input_Length: integer;
  Input_Buffer: TByteArray;

begin
  with AContext.Connection do
  begin
    IOHandler.ReadBytes(Socket_Receive_Buffer, -1, false);
    Socket_Input_Length := Length(Socket_Receive_Buffer);
    if Socket_Input_Length > 0 then
    begin
      BytesToRaw(Socket_Receive_Buffer,Input_Buffer,Socket_Input_Length);
      Terminal.GuiTerminalPutInput(Input_Buffer, Socket_Input_Length);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `BytesToRaw()` requires the output buffer to be pre-allocated to the correct length first. You are not doing that, so it should be crashing since `Input_Buffer` is nil. That being said, `TIdBytes` and `TByteArray` are both dynamic arrays of bytes.  They are not assignment compatible, but they have compatible memory layouts, so a simply typecast would suffice: `Terminal.GuiTerminalPutInput(PByteArray(@Socket_Receive_Buffer)^, Socket_Input_Length);`

Comment: Otherwise, change `GuiTerminalPutInput()` to accept a `PByte` or `Pointer` in the first parameter, then you can use this instead: `Terminal.GuiTerminalPutInput(@Socket_Receive_Buffer[0], Socket_Input_Length);` or this: `Terminal.GuiTerminalPutInput(PByte(Socket_Receive_Buffer), Socket_Input_Length);`  If you are going to keep passing a `TByteArray` (or any other dynamic array), there is no need to pass the array's length as a separate parameter, a dynamic array knows its own length, so `GuiTerminalPutInput()` could simply use `Length()` on its input array when needed.